# Is Zeitgeist installed as part of Ubuntu Minimal?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I'm having major problems with Ubuntu crashing every day so I'd like to try something different. I tried Googling for a list of packages in Oneiric Ubuntu Minimal but couldn't find anything.

I'd like to try a system that doesn't have Zeitgeist installed, but as it seems to be so tightly integrated into Ubuntu I wondered if it was still present in the Minimal version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As far as I'm aware, Zeitgeist currently is only used in Gnome.

Comment: I know this is old, but for anybody new coming here, Zeitgeist is currently installed and used by default in Ubuntu now. Not sure about Minimal, though.